# Are there chromosomes that we inherit that are not recombinated?

Tags: genetics, chromosome, recombination

We do have chromosomes that recombinated ,but aren't there pure chromosomes that are not recombinated that people would have?

Answer (score 2):

As you say `people`, I will assume you are talking about humans only.

Except for the small [pseudo-autosomal regions (PAR1, PAR2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoautosomal_region), the Y-chromosome and the X-chromosome do not recombine together. This means that if you are a girl, then you have inherited a X chromosome from your father who did not recombine in your father (but might have recombined in your father's mother if that's where this chromosome come from). If you are a boy, then you have inherited a Y chromosome from your father who never recombines.

There is also [mitochondrial DNA (mtDNA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_DNA) that does not recombine but mtDNA is not organized into chromosome.

Comment: what can cause a y chromosome and x chromosome to recombine?

Comment: Y and X chromosome recombine at the pseudoautosomal regions. It seems that those regions exist to allow segregation of the two chromosomes during meiosis.

Comment: so why can't normal y chromosome recombine?

Comment: Do you mean "why can't the non PAR part of the Y recombine?"?